# Why do my eloquent queries get overwritten when used later?

Tags: php, laravel, eloquent

I've encountered a very strange problem and I cannot find the cause of it. I was wondering if someone has encountered the same problem or if its a config problem.

Basically this was my block of code. Very simple stuff.

```
$productImages = App\ProductImage::where('product_id', $product->id)->orderBy("order", "asc");
$productImages_First = $productImages->first();
$productImages_All = $productImages->get();
```

If I performed a dump and die on `$productImages_All` then it would output the following:

```
Collection {
  #items: array:5
}
```

This has worked perfectly fine for months. I haven't touched this block of code at all.

However, I've noticed in the last week, that if I dump and die `$productImages_All` now, it will only return the first image and not all of them.

```
Collection {
  #items: array:1
}
```

It seems that the `$productImages_First = $productImages->first();` is overwriting it. Is this standard behaviour? It would make complete sense if it was as its calling to the original eloquent query and I should create a separate one to get all of the images. However,  what doesn't make sense is that this block of code has worked for months without a change and it has randomly broke.

I can fix this very quickly, I just want to see if I can get more clarity on what may cause this?

Comment: maybe there is a changes on your data? it looks fine for me.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That's because when you call first method it modifies the **Query/Builder** object inside the **Eloquent/Builder** and sets limit property to 1, so you have to reset it's value before calling get method.

```
$productImages = App\ProductImage::where('product_id', $product->id)- 
>orderBy("order", "asc");
$productImages_First = (clone $productImages)->first();
$productImages_All = $productImages->get();
```

Or you can

```
$productImages = App\ProductImage::where('product_id', $product->id)- 
>orderBy("order", "asc");
$productImages_First = $productImages->first();
$productImages->getQuery()->limit=null;
$productImages_All = $productImages->get();
```

Comment: The answer has been modified please check it out.

Comment: That's awesome. Thank you. I wasn't aware that there was such a thing as `clone`!